# Java swing JTextArea & JScrollPane, vertical scrolling works but not horizontally, one line goes down

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I am working on a java gui project. I want to add scoll to JTextArea component. Even though I added it, only Vertical scroll works. That's why the text goes to the bottom line. I do not want this, so 2'scroll can be used at the same time so that the text does not boil over to the bottom line.

My class :

```
package net.macesdev.duckclient.installer;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class DebugConsole {
    public static void runWindow() {
        
        // THEME_MANAGER
        
        try {
             UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");  // This line gives Windows Theme
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        // CREATING_COMPOMENTS
        
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        ImageIcon app_logo_image = new ImageIcon(DebugConsole.class.getResource("/net/macesdev/duckclient/installer/app_logo.png"));
        
        // COMPOMENT_SETTINGS
        
        Font mainTextF = new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 11);
        
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 20);  
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (textArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  

        // scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(window.getPreferredSize()));
        scroll.setSize(new Dimension(700, 700));
        
        window.getContentPane().add(scroll);

        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        
        textArea.setFont(mainTextF);
        textArea.setBounds(10, 10, 465, 540);
        textArea.setText("null");
        textArea.setColumns(70);
        
        // FRAME & PANEL SETTINGS
        
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setTitle("Duck Client Installer - Debug Console");
        window.setIconImage(app_logo_image.getImage());
        window.setResizable(true);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        int formSizeX = 500;
        int formSizeY = 600;
        window.setSize(formSizeX,formSizeY);
    }
}
```

I've been working on it for several hours, but I couldn't find much useful information. Can you help me?

[anormal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HguMY.png)

Comment: The calls to `setSize(..);` & `setBounds(..)` are at best pointless (as in the above code) or at worst counter-productive. Don't do either. `window.setSize(formSizeX,formSizeY);` Don't do that either. Instead do `window.pack();` and the GUI will be the size it needs to be. For an example of a code problem, also don't futz about with setting icons or fonts. Posted code should focus on the actual problem. `// This line gives Windows Theme` Not on a Mac or Linux / Unix machine it doesn't. They would not have the Windows PLAF installed.

Comment: You turned line wrapping on so the text will always wrap which means there is no need for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Well, is your problem solved? Either comment that the suggestions helped, or provide more information to the problem.

Comment: @camickr yes, sorry for the late reply (I was busy)